# Configure ServiceCollection via JSON file

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, .net-core

Is there an example of configuring dependency injection in .NET Core 2.0 via a JSON file that would contain *interface -> class mappings*? E.g.

```
var someServiceConfigBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
someServiceConfigBuilder.AddJsonFile("someservice.json");
var someServiceConfig = someServiceConfigBuilder.Build();

var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddOptions();
services.Configure<SomeServiceOptions>(someServiceConfig);
services
    // TODO this should really come from the JSON config file
    .AddTransient<ISomeService, SomeService>();
```

So rather than hard-coding the mappings with calls to `AddTransient()`, it'd be great to have this info coming from the JSON file.

Is this supported? If yes, what's the expected format of the JSON config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Replacing the default services container**
>
> The built-in services container **is meant to serve the basic needs of
>   the framework and most consumer applications built on it**. However,
>   developers can replace the built-in container with their preferred
>   container. The `ConfigureServices` method typically returns void, but if
>   its signature is changed to return `IServiceProvider`, a different
>   container can be configured and returned. There are many IOC
>   containers available for .NET.

(Emphasis mine)

Reference: [Introduction to Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#replacing-the-default-services-container)

With that I would suggest checking to see if there are already 3rd party DI frameworks that provide the feature and has an extension that can integrate with .Net Core.

> #### Note
>
> When using a third-party DI container, you must change `ConfigureServices` so that it returns `IServiceProvider` instead of `void`.

Comment: Looks like Autofac is the preferred container over the standard implementation, and it does support Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration JSON configs. http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/xml.html
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void Injection(IServiceCollection services)

 {

  var jsonServices = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("dependency.json"))["services"];

  var requiredServices = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < List < Service >> (jsonServices.ToString());

  foreach(var service in requiredServices)

  {

   var serviceType = Type.GetType(service.ServiceType.Trim() + ", " + service.Assembly.Trim());

   var implementationType = Type.GetType(service.ImplementationType.Trim() + ", " + service.Assembly.Trim());

   var serviceLifetime = (ServiceLifetime) Enum.Parse(typeof(ServiceLifetime), service.Lifetime.Trim());

   var serviceDescriptor = new ServiceDescriptor(serviceType: serviceType,

    implementationType: implementationType,

    lifetime: serviceLifetime);

   services.Add(serviceDescriptor);

  }
```

For more details please click [here](http://shebin.tech/asp-net-core-dependency-injection-from-json-files/)